# Getting Rid of Multiple Names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert multi-name column to a sigle-name column in python. Right now, the column names look like this:

```
   [('passengers', 'January'),
   ('passengers', 'February'),
   ('passengers', 'March'),
   ('passengers', 'April'),
   ('passengers', 'December'),
   'Total']
```

But I am trying to get this:

```
  ['January',
   'February',
   'March',
   'April',
   'December',
   'Total']
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pandas :-):

```
l=[('passengers', 'January'),
   ('passengers', 'February'),
   ('passengers', 'March'),
   ('passengers', 'April'),
   ('passengers', 'December'),
   'Total'] # Or pandas then get data to list.
print([i[-1] if isinstance(i,tuple) else i for i in l])
```

Output:

```
['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'December', 'Total']
```

Comment: Nice python way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention pandas

```
pd.Series(l).apply(pd.Series).ffill(1)[1]
Out[92]: 
0     January
1    February
2       March
3       April
4    December
5       Total
Name: 1, dtype: object

pd.Series(l).apply(pd.Series).ffill(1)[1].tolist()
Out[93]: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'December', 'Total']
```